# Geometric interpretation of $\|a+b\|^2 +\|a-b\|^2 = 2 \|a\|^2 +2\|b\|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inner-products

For vectors $a,b$ in an inner product space, I have just proven the identity:
$$\|a + b\|^2 + \|a - b \|^2 = 2\|a\|^2 + 2\|b\|^2$$
Now I am trying to visualise this in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I'm having a hard time drawing out what this means. Isn't 
it basically saying that, in a parallelogram the squared lengths of the diagonals add up to the squared lengths of 
the sides of the parallelogram?

Comment: Think about the triangle formed by the vectors $\overline{a+b}$ and $\overline{a-b}$ What about the triangle formed by the vectors $\overline{\sqrt2a}$ and $\overline{\sqrt2b}$?

Comment: Yes, see [Parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law. Greetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

We can see that $A+B$ and $A-B$ represents the diagonals while vectors $A$ and $B$ are the sides of the parallogram.

Comment: (+1) and one nitpicking: Label "A-B" and orientation of the diagonal are not consistent.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't realized that until now.

Comment: Just a curiosity: being $|\mathbf A|>|\mathbf B|$ the verse of the vector difference $\mathbf A-\mathbf B$ can go from the tip of $\mathbf B$ to the tip of $\mathbf A$?

Comment: yes, $A-B$ is the vector that can be obtained by traveling from $B$ to $A$.

Answer (score 0):

No. It means that the sum of the squares of the diagonals is equal to the sum of the squares of all sides.

Comment: Yeah my bad, that's what I meant.